# Recursive java program doesn't return any value. Putting a print statement right before the return statements prints infinite values

Tags: java, recursion, infinite-loop

```
//inefficient recursive algorithm to find number of coins needed for a some amount
public class bitcoin {

    public int mincoins;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] coins = {1, 5, 10, 21, 25};
        int change = 63;
        int min = 0;
        min = MinCoins(coins, change);
        System.out.println(min);
    }

    public static int MinCoins(int[] coins, int change) {
        int mincoins = change;
        int mincoins1 = 10000;

        for (int j = 0; j <= coins.length - 1; j++) {
            if (coins[j] == change) //base case
                return 1;
        }

        //recursive call breaking into two sub problems
        for (int i = 1; i <= (change) / 2; i++) {
            mincoins1 = (MinCoins(coins, i) + MinCoins(coins, (change - i)));

            if (mincoins1 < change)
                mincoins = mincoins1;
        }

        return mincoins;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code. It's impossible to read.

Comment: Format your code, using your IDE, the post it, as code, in your question. There is a preview when posting. Use it, and don't press the submit button until the code looks perfect there. It's not that hard. While you're at it, respect the Java naming conventions.

Comment: And please add explanatory text in your question as well. You appear to be asking without first reading *how* to ask, and this is not wise. Please review these sections in the [help] soon.

Comment: This is my first time here. Will incorporate the changes.

Comment: Can you use each coin an infinite amount of times?

Comment: Sanity check!  `if (mincoins1 < change)...` is comparing `mincoins1`, a number of coins, with `change`, a currency amount.  How does that make sense?  That the next line is `mincoins = mincoins1` suggests maybe the test should have been `if (mincoins1 < mincoins)...`?

Comment: "change",which is the currency amount can be thought of as 1*currency . Which is the case when total amount is expressed in one unit denominations.(worst case).

Answer (score 0):

As your comment suggests, this is a inefficient recursive algorithm. But by moving your code around a bit, at least is doesn't loop forever. Instead, it eventually finds a solution (and for all tests I've made, it has found the optimal coin count).

The part you missed was an exit-on-fail criterion. In this example:

```
If the coin sum is more than 'change', give up.
(For example, if you have already added 3 coins with value 25 (total 75), there are no
coins that can help you reach 63, so stop trying to find them.)
```

This if statement (see below) handles the exit-on-fail:

```
if (change - coins[j] >= 0)

public static int MinCoins(int[] coins, int change) {
    int mindepth = 10000;
    for (int j = 0; j < coins.length; j++) {
        if (coins[j] == change) {
            return 1; // end case
        } else if (change - coins[j] >= 0) {
            int depth = 1 + MinCoins(coins, change - coins[j]);
            if (depth >= 0 && depth < mindepth) {
                mindepth = depth;
            }
        }
    }
    return mindepth;
}
```